# Bootable USB Windows 7 installation not working

Tags: windows-7, usb, bootable-media

I am trying to create a bootable USB drive to install Windows 7 from USB drive but it is not working. I've set USB as primary boot device but nothing happens.

The steps I followed to make it bootable are from:

http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/2/

I've followed the steps till assign and then basically copied all contents from my DVD drive into USB drive. Then I went into BIOS and set USB as primary boot device.

But it's not taking up. Any ideas why? Is there any mistake I made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has created a tool designed to burn a Windows 7 Install Image to DVD or USB automatically. Take a look at [USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) and it might take care of what you are trying to do.

If you are using tool to create a bootable USB for Win7 64 bit then make sure that you do it on computer that is running Win 7 64bit. If you create a bootable 64bit Win 7 USB from within Win 7 32bit then it won't work.